# vmap in Jax to loop over arguments

Tags: python, arrays, jax

Lets suppose I have some function which returns a sum of inputs.

```
@jit
def some_func(a,r1,r2):
    return a + r1 + r2
```

Now I would like to loop over different values of `r1` and `r2`, save the result and add it to a counter. This is what I mean:

```
a = 0 
r1 = jnp.arange(0,3)
r2 = jnp.arange(0,3)


s = 0 
for i in range(len(r1)): 
    for j in range(len(r2)): 
        s+= some_func(a, r1[i], r2[j])
    
print(s)
DeviceArray(18, dtype=int32)
```

My question is, how do I do this with `jax.vmap` to avoid writing the `for` loops? I have something like this so far:

```
vmap(some_func, in_axes=(None, 0,0), out_axes=0)(jnp.arange(0,3), jnp.arange(0,3))
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: vmap in_axes specification must be a tree prefix of the corresponding value, got specification (None, 0, 0) for value tree PyTreeDef((*, *)).
```

I have a feeling that the error is in `in_axes` but I am not sure how to get `vmap` to pick a value for `r1` loop over `r2` and then do the same for all `r1` whilst saving intermediate results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would like to do this with Jax only.

Answer (score 2):

`vmap` will map over a single axis at a time. Because you want to map over two different axes, you'll need two `vmap` calls:

```python
func_mapped = vmap(vmap(some_func, (None, 0, None)), (None, None, 0))
func_mapped(a, r1, r2).sum()
# 18
```

Alternatively, for a simple function like this you can avoid `vmap` and use numpy-style broadcasting to get the same result:

```python
some_func(a, r1[None, :, None], r2[None, None, :]).sum()
# 18
```